# Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string ember-cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to set [ember-cli.photoswipe](https://github.com/poetic/ember-cli-photoswipe) locally and i come across to this issue:

- Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string TypeError: Cannot convert a
- Symbol value to a string
- Symbol.hasOwnProperty

Symbols don't coerce to strings on their own

[image]

These are the steps

after all these steps

- git clone https://github.com/DanyHunter/ember-cli-photoswipe.git
- ember install:addon ember-cli-photoswipe
- ember server

My ember cli version is : "ember-cli": "0.1.7"

How can i sort it out?

Comment: which version of node are you on?

Comment: node v0.12.0, it's the current one

Comment: It's a known bug in 0.12.0, you might have to downgrade to 0.11.16 https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/9363. You can use NVM (node version manager)

Comment: same error with  0.11.16

Comment: I suggest filing an issue on the addon repo